# BeautifulSoup - Get Text within tag only if a certain string is found

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some scripts from a TV-Show. I am able to get the text as I need it using BeautifulSoup and Requests.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for p in s.find_all('p'):
    print p.text
```

This works great so far. But I want only those paragraphs from a certain character. Say his name is "stackoverflow". The text would be like this:

A: sdasd sd asda
B: sdasds
STACKOVERFLOW: Help?

So I only want the stuff that STACKOVERFLOW says. Not the rest.

I have tried

```
s.find_all(text='STACKOVERFLOW') but I get nothing.
```

What would be the right way  to do  this? A hint in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Make the *partial* text match, either with:

```
s.find_all(text=lambda text: text and 'STACKOVERFLOW' in text)
```

Or:

```
import re

s.find_all(text=re.compile('STACKOVERFLOW'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom function to pass into `find_all`. This function should take in one argument (tag) and return `True` for the tags that meet your criteria.

```
def so_tags(tag):
    '''returns True if the tag has text and 'stackoverflow' is in the text'''
    return (tag.text and "STACKOVERFLOW" in tag.text)

soup.find_all(my_tags)
```

You could also make a function factory to make it a bit more dynamic.

```
def user_paragraphs(user):
    '''returns a function'''
    def user_tags(tag):
        '''returns True for tags that have <user> in the text'''
        return (tag.text and user in tag.text)
    return user_tags

for user in user_list:
    user_posts = soup.find_all(user_paragraphs(user))
```