# What usage is the anonymous function in findAll?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing some tables w/ BeautifulSoup, and came across an easy way to pick out the table's `td` and `th` tags. Try as I might, though, I don't know **why** this particular bit of code works (specifically: the very last line).

```
response = urlopen(url)
table = SoupStrainer('table',{'border': 0, 'cellpadding': 5})
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parseOnlyThese = table)
soup.findAll(lamba tag: tag.name == "td")
```

What's the point of defining the anonymous function, `dat`? I've tried `soup.findAll(name == "td")` which doesn't work, but `soup.findAll(lambda grop: grop.name == "td")` works. How is this lambda function interacting with BeautifulSoup and why do I need it? Is there another way of writing the same code that makes things a bit more clear?

Comment: `soup.findAll(name == "td")` is very different from `soup.findAll(name = "td")`. The latter might have worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `find*()` functions in `BeautifulSoup` can be [a function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function).

In this particular case:

```
soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == "td")
```

is really an overkill and is equivalent to:

```
soup.findAll("td")
```

---

A function can also be used to filter a specific attribute, for example:

```
soup.find_all("a", href=lambda href: href and href.startswith("http"))
```

Some of the real-world use cases:

- [How to find all divs who's class starts with a string in BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465182/how-to-find-all-divs-whos-class-starts-with-a-string-in-beautifulsoup/35465898#35465898)
- [BeautifulSoup - Get Text within tag only if a certain string is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221191/beautifulsoup-get-text-within-tag-only-if-a-certain-string-is-found)
- [using bs4 to find a html tag (h2) having text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511490/using-bs4-to-find-a-html-tag-h2-having-text)

Answer (score 0):

In BS4, there are five filter in the `find()`, function is one of them:

You can define a function that takes an element as its only argument. The function should return True if the argument matches, and False otherwise.

It does not matter how you function defined, as long it takes an element.